# Starting a CDI conversation and injecting @ConversationScoped bean into stateless session bean

Tags: java, cdi, stateless-session-bean, conversation-scope, seam-conversation

Similar questions have been asked, but don't quite address what I'm trying to do.  We have an older Seam 2.x-based application with a batch job framework that we are converting to CDI.  The job framework uses the Seam Contexts object to initiate a conversation.  The job framework also loads a job-specific data holder (basically a Map) that can then be accessed, via the Seam Contexts object, by any service down the chain, including from SLSBs.  Some of these services can update the Map, so that job state can change and be detected from record to record.

It looks like in CDI, the job will `@Inject` a CDI Conversation object, and manually begin/end the conversation.  We would also define a new `ConversationScoped` bean that holds the Map (`MapBean`).  What's not clear to me are two things:

First, the job needs to also @Inject the `MapBean` so that it can be loaded with job-specific data before the Conversation.begin() method is called.  Would the container know to pass this instance to services down the call chain?

Related to that, according to this question [Is it possible to @Inject a @RequestScoped bean into a @Stateless EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717022/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-requestscoped-bean-into-a-stateless-ejb) it should be possible to inject a `ConservationScoped` bean into a SLSB, but it seems a bit magical.  If the SLSB is used by a different process (job, UI call, etc), does it get separate instance for each call?

**Edits for clarification and a simplified class structure:**

`MapBean` would need to be a `ConversationScoped` object, containing data for a specific instance/run of a job.

```
@ConversationScoped
public class MapBean implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, Object> data;
    // accessors
    public Object getData(String key) {
        return data.get(key);
    }
    public void setData(String key, Object value) {
        data.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

The job would be `ConversationScoped`:

```
@ConversationScoped
public class BatchJob {
    @Inject private MapBean mapBean;
    @Inject private Conversation conversation;
    @Inject private JobProcessingBean jobProcessingBean;
    public void runJob() {
        try {
            conversation.begin();
            mapBean.setData("key", "value");  // is this MapBean instance now bound to the conversation?
            jobProcessingBean.doWork();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // catch something
        } finally {
            conversation.end();
        }
    }
}
```

The job might call a SLSB, and the current conversation-scoped instance of `MapBean` needs to be available:

```
@Stateless
public class JobProcessingBean {
    @Inject private MapBean mapBean;

    public void doWork() {
        // when this is called, is "mapBean" the current conversation instance?
        Object value = mapBean.getData("key");
    }
}
```

Our job and SLSB framework is quite complex, the SLSB can call numerous other services or locally instantiated business logic classes, and each of these would need access to the conversation-scoped `MapBean`.

Comment: In short: yes and yes. Your design should be fine in general. Would have to try later today and post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, the job needs to also `@Inject` the `MapBean` so that it can be loaded with job-specific data before the `Conversation.begin()` method is called. Would the container know to pass this instance to services down the call chain?

Yes, since `MapBean` is `@ConversationScoped` it is tied to the call chain for the duration starting from `conversation.begin()` until `conversation.end()`. You can think of `@ConversationScoped` (and `@RequestScoped` and `@SessionScoped`) as instances in [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) - while there exists an instance of them for every thread, each instance is tied to that single thread.

> Related to that, according to this question [Is it possible to @Inject a @RequestScoped bean into a @Stateless EJB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8717022/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-requestscoped-bean-into-a-stateless-ejb) it should be possible to inject a `@ConservationScoped` bean into a SLSB, but it seems a bit magical. If the SLSB is used by a different process (job, UI call, etc), does it get separate instance for each call?

It's not as magical as you think if you see that this pattern is the same as the one I explained above. The SLSB indeed gets a separate instance, but not just any instance, the one which belongs to the scope from which the SLSB was called.

In addition to the link you posted, see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45256562/1803551).

Iv'e tested a similar code to what you posted and it works as expected - the `MapBean` is the same one injected throughout the call. Just be careful with 2 things:

- `BatchJob` is also `@ConversationScoped` but does not implement `Serializable`, which will not allow the bean to passivate.
- `data` is not initialized, so you will get an NPE in `runJob()`.

Comment: Thanks, tried to up the "helpful" count, but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @whafrog No problem, come back when you have enough rep if you want to :) It's important though to select an answer as accepted (green checkmark) to mark that the question was solved. You also get 2 rep points for doing so.

Comment: Yeah, flagging the answer as accepted gave me just enough...  :)

Answer (score 0):

Without any code samples, I'll have to do some guessing, so let's see if I got you right.

> Would the container know to pass this instance to services down the call chain?

If you mean to use the same instance elsewhere in the call, then this can be easily achieved by making the `MapBean` an `@ApplicationScoped` bean (or, alternatively, and EJB `@Singleton`).

> it should be possible to inject a ConservationScoped bean into a SLSB, but it seems a bit magical.

Here I suppose that the reason why it seems magical is that SLSB is in terms of CDI a `@Dependent` bean. And as you probably know, CDI always creates new instance for dependent bean injection point. E.g. yes, you get a different SLS/Dependent bean instance for each call.

Perhaps some other scope would fit you better here? Like `@RequestScoped` or `@SessionScoped`? Hard to tell without more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the question with a simplified class structure, hope that makes more sense.  If I could I would rewrite our framework, but it's a massive project so I have to find the simplest way to rip out Seam and replace it with CDI.

Comment: @whafrog I see; that's quite different from what I initially understood. Anyway the answer to both your questions should be "yes" - the two conversation scoped beans will should definitely work together. And you can inject conversation scoped one into stateless bean. Is there something that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'm still working through a simplified POC, but at least I seem to be on the right track.  One detail I left out that I'm now trying to resolve is that in the old system the BatchJob also registered as a JMX bean so it could be called remotely from a batch scheduler.  So I think I need to refactor out the JMX part (I don't see that working with @ConversationScoped) to a separate bean that calls the BatchJob.  I still want the BatchJob to start the Conversation, so I'm guessing I wouldn't @Inject the BatchJob into the JmxBean, I would just create a new instance...?