# "Unexpected invocation state 0" error in Wildfly

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, cdi, ejb-3.2

I created a small example that demonstrates the error.

A stateful bean holds a list as its state and injects a stateless bean:

```
@Stateful
@RequestScoped
public class StatefulBean {

    @Inject
    StatelessBean slsb;

    @Getter // public list getter
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<String> sfAdd() {
        slsb.slAdd();
        System.out.println(list);
        list.add("Z");
        return list;
    }
}
```

The stateless bean manipulates the state of the stateful bean by injection:

```
@Stateless
public class StatelessBean {

    @Inject
    StatefulBean sfsb;

    public void slAdd() {
        sfsb.getList().add("S");
    }
}
```

The call `System.out.println(sfsb.sfAdd());` is made in a JAXRS GET method. The steps of the invocation that I expected are are:

1. `sfAdd` is called
2. `slAdd` is called and adds `"S"`, return.
3. print `[S]`.
4. add `"Z"`, return.
5. print `[S, Z]`.

Which in general is what happens, but the ouput gives an error message also:

```
INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) [S]

ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (default task-2) WFLYEJB0487: Unexpected invocation state 0
INFO  [stdout] (default task-2) [S, Z]
```

I don't understand what is `WFLYEJB0487: Unexpected invocation state 0`, why it happens and what I'm supposed to do about it. The message is printed between steps 3 and 5. Google found only https://developer.jboss.org/thread/272767 but it's not helpful.

I also found out that removing `@Stateful` from `StatefulBean` causes the error to disappear. Wildfly 10.1, JavaEE 7.

Comment: Where is your `getList()` on your `StatefulBean` class?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Oh, there's Lombok's `@Getter` annotation on the list which generates a getter. I'll mention that.

Comment: Looks like a bug in Wildfly. Removing `@Stateful` clears the error message because the bug is triggered by a transactional [interceptor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.wildfly/wildfly-ejb3/9.0.1.Final/org/jboss/as/ejb3/component/stateful/StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor.java#StatefulSessionSynchronizationInterceptor) that affects only SFSBs. Unless you're managing transactions in your use case, you shouldn't worry (or upgrade).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java EE 6: How to call Stateful Session Bean from Stateless Session Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437206/java-ee-6-how-to-call-stateful-session-bean-from-stateless-session-bean)

Comment: @SteveC No, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249780/how-to-make-a-state-available-to-all-beans-in-a-session and the discussions in there.

Comment: Well, is it EJB 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2? You have tagged it with "ejb-3.0".

Comment: @SteveC Java ee 7 with wildfly 10.1, so I guess ejb 3.2.